# Showing that $\mathrm{Var}(X)=\mathrm{Var}(Y)$

Tags: calculus, probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be continuous random variables with the following PDF $(b>a)$:
[image]

Show that $\mathrm{Var}(X)=\mathrm{Var}(Y)$.

Here is my attempt:
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Var}(X)&=\mathbb{E}(X^2)-(\mathbb{E}(X))^2 = \int_1^2 bx^2 \, dx + \int_2^4 ax^2 \, dx - \left(\int_1^2 bx \, dx + \int_2^4 ax \, dx\right)^2\\
&=\frac{7b+56a}{3}-\frac{9b^2}{4}-18ba-36a^2\\
\mathrm{Var}(Y)&=\mathbb{E}(Y^2)-(\mathbb{E}(Y))^2 = \int_2^4 ay^2\, dy - \int_4^5 by^2\, dy - \left(\int_2^4 ay\, dy - \int_4^5 by\, dy\right)^2\\
&=\frac{56a-61b}{3}-36a^2+54ab-\frac{81b^2}{4}
\end{align*}

Comment: These are not pdfs. The area under the graphs will not evaluate to 1, but to $b+2a$.

Comment: @Snake707 Yes, but I think that means we can assume $b+2a=1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use the symmetry of the problem. Given a random variable $X$ with the first distribution, $Y=6-X$ will have the other distribution. Thus,
$$
\newcommand{\Var}{\mathrm{Var}}
\Var(Y) = \Var(6-X) = \Var(X).
$$

Comment: Should be accepted solution.

Comment: Yes you are right. This definitely simplifies the working.

Answer (score 2):

$Var(X)$ is correct but there are mistakes in signs while calculation $Var(Y)$.

\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Var}(X)&=\mathbb{E}(X^2)-(\mathbb{E}(X))^2 = \int_1^2 bx^2 \, dx + \int_2^4 ax^2 \, dx - \left(\int_1^2 bx \, dx + \int_2^4 ax \, dx\right)^2\\
&=\frac{7b+56a}{3}- \left(6a+\frac{3b}{2}\right)^2\\
\mathrm{Var}(Y)&=\mathbb{E}(Y^2)-(\mathbb{E}(Y))^2 = \int_2^4 ay^2\, dy + \int_4^5 by^2\, dy - \left(\int_2^4 ay\, dy + \int_4^5 by\, dy\right)^2\\
&=\frac{56a+61b}{3}- \left(6a+\frac{9b}{2}\right)^2
\end{align*}

$ \displaystyle Var(Y) - Var(X) = 18b + \left(6a+\frac{3b}{2}\right)^2 - \left(6a+\frac{9b}{2}\right)^2$

$ \displaystyle = 18b - 36 ab - 18b^2$

Now given the pdf, we also note that $2a + b = 1 \implies 2a = 1 - b$

So, $ \displaystyle Var(Y) - Var(X) = 18b - 18 b (1-b) - 18b^2 = 0$

Answer (score 0):

**These are not necessarily pdfs since the integral under those curves does not necessarily evaluate to one, but $b+2a$, which could be anything!!!**

However these could be two probability spaces $\Omega=[1,4]$ and $\Omega'=[2,5]$. The probability measure on both is given by $\frac 13 \mathcal{L}$ (the Lebesgue measure divided by $3$). There are random variables $X$ defined on $\Omega$ and $Y$ on $\Omega'$. There is a mapping $f:\Omega\rightarrow \Omega', s\mapsto 6-s$ that takes both $\Omega$ to $\Omega'$ and $X$ to $Y$ in the sense: $X = Y \circ f$. Denote the pdf of $X$ by $\psi_X$ and the pdf of $Y$ by $\psi_Y$. By the same token $\psi_X=\psi_Y\circ f\cdot f'$.

Now we can write

$$\mathbb{E}[Y^k]=\int_2^5 Y(s)^k \psi_Y(s)\mathrm{d}y.$$

Now substitute $t=6-s$ and we have

$$=\int_4^1 Y(6-t)^k \underbrace{\psi_Y(6-t) (6-t)'}_{\psi_X(t)}\mathrm{d}t = \int_1^4 X(t)^k \psi_X(t)\mathrm{d}t=\mathbb{E}[X^k].$$

Comment: The question clearly states $a$ and $b$ are pdfs and hence $2a + b = 1$.